# How to launch multiple instances of a program in parallel using parallel?

Tags: linux, curl, gnu-parallel

I would like to execute a command:

```
curl example.com
```

multiple times in parallel using GNU parallel. I tried:

```
parallel -j 3 curl example.com
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: That's it. Thank you @don_crissti :) Can you add your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: "Using parallel to run script without input" wasn't was I was searching for. But thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As @don_crissti points out:

```
seq 3 | parallel -n0 curl example.com
```

Comment: What is this `-n0`? Is there a `-n1`?

Comment: -n0 = read one argument, but throw it away. -n1 = read one argument and use it.